# C++ using ldap_bind from ldap.h

Tags: c++, ldap, openldap

I'm trying to use ldap_bind, but get an this error.

```
error: âldap_bindâ was not declared in this scope
```

code:

```
#include <lber.h>
#include <ldap.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    LDAP *ld;

    char *ldap_host = "ldap://localhost";
    int ldap_port   = 389;
    int auth_method = LDAP_AUTH_SIMPLE;
    int desired_version = LDAP_VERSION3;
    char *root_dn   = "ou=people,dc=localhost,dc=local";
    char *root_ps   = "password";

    int result;

    result = ldap_initialize(&ld, ldap_host);

    cout << "result: " << result << endl;

    result = ldap_set_option(ld, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, &desired_version);

    cout << "result: " << result << endl;

    result = ldap_bind_s(ld, root_dn, root_ps, auth_method);

    cout << "result: " << result << endl;
}
```

I'm compiling with this command

```
g++ ldap.cpp -llber -lldap -o prog
```

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've no experience with OpenLDAP, but from the header it seems you need:

```
extern "C" {
# define LDAP_DEPRECATED
# include <ldap.h>
# include <lber.h>
}
```

Comment: After looking through the code, I had to define LDAP_DEPRECATED, so you are correct. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It leads to some compiling errors in current version, since in the `ldap.h` use `#if LDAP_DEPRECATED` instead of `#ifdef`, give the MACRO a value:

```
#define LDAP_DEPRECATED 1
```

And it is good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Dont use ldap_bind. Its deprecated. Rather use `ldap_sasl_bind`.
ldap.h has deprecated a lot of functions for mostly security reasons

Check out the following command which lists all the deprecated functions

```
grep deprecate < /usr/include/ldap.h
```

Answer (score 0):

On *nix systems, or any system that let's you specify compilation flags, you can add the following to your list of flags:

```
-DLDAP_DEPRECATED
```

This allows you to use the deprecated deprecated features without having to add defines to the top of all of your source/header files.